# MATLAB disabled status in Yosemite

Tags: applications, macos

I have 2013a installed and the patch from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1098655). The patch should work, but when I navigate to the application, there is a "stop" icon above the app icon [image]which still prevents the patched version from launching. How can I remove this disabled status? For now I can only launch matlab from inside the app content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. After the 10.10.1 update, the disabled status icon is gone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to [this bug report](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1116607).

Does the application run if you open it via terminal? e.g

```
open /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app
```

if so you may just need to clear dock/icon caches:

```
killall -HUP Dock
```

Comment: Well. This doesn' t work. It still stays at disabled status after reboot. Run via terminal works, as I mentioned.